# Update a progressbar when steps are arbitrary

Tags: c#, floating-point, int, progress-bar

I am writing a C# application where I process lines in a file. The file may have 2 lines, 30, 80, maybe over a hundred lines.

The lines are stored in a list, so I can get the line count from `myFileList.Count`. The progressbar only takes `int` as arguments to the value, so if I have line number of say 50, I could easily do

```
int steps = 100/myFileList.Count 
progress += steps; 
updateProgressBar ( progress );
```

But what if my file has say 61 lines: 100/61 = 1,64, hence `int steps` will be equal to 1 and my progress bar will stop at 61 percent. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I'm assuming you're using the [System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.aspx).

Instead of trying to calculate the percentage of progress, simply set the value of the [Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx) field to the number of lines. Then you can set the value to the line number you're at instead, and it'll automatically convert it to a suitable percentage.

```
// At some point when you start your computation:
pBar.Maximum = myFileList.Count;

// Whenever you want to update the progress:
pBar.Value = progress;

// Alternatively you can increment the progress by the number of lines processed
// since last update:
pBar.Increment(dLines);
```

Answer (score 2):

define `progress` as `double` and change the code:

```
double steps = 100d/myFileList.Count;
progress += steps; 
updateProgressBar ((int) progress );
```

Comment: This is actual the answer I need. I use an event listener to update the progress bar, so I don't want to change the `Maximum` value of it through the event. Even so, I forgot to mention this in my question so I have to go with Sebastians.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen I don't get why you prefer the Sebastians' answer when you have restrictions on Maximum value?

Comment: Since that was the most elegant solution to the question asked (The question doesn't mention anything about restrictions)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are working on WinForms application

why are you using 100 here ?

ProgressBar has a Maximum property that you can set to total septs

e.g.

```
ProgressBar1.Maximum = myFileList.Count;
```

and after that in the loop you can do a trick like this

```
ProgressBar1.value =0;
for(int i=0;i<myFileList.Count;i++){

 //your code here

 ProgressBar1.value++;
}
```

that's it !